# Is there a way to use PowerShell to move a table down on the page on a Word document?

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I am running into issues pasting a table at the beginning of a document. I was using the ActiveDocument.Range(0,0) method to paste a table into a document that has another table, and I wanted the new table to be before the new one; however, I ran into an issue with the table pasting itself into the first row of a table if the table is already at the beginning of the document. I tried "InsertBefore", but this did not work either.

I think I have tried every method I could find on Microsoft's Documentation. My work around was to cut any table at the top of the document and move it down, using "Selection.MoveDown". This has not worked though. Is there an easier way to move tables in a word document?

I tried this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$directory = "C:\temp"
$DocxFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $directory -Filter "*.docx" 
$counter = 1 

#Menu
Write-Host "==========" -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
Write-Host "===MENU===" -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
Write-Host "==========" -BackgroundColor DarkGreen

$(for($i=0; $i -lt $DocxFiles.Count; $i++){
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'File Name'       = "${i}: $($DocxFiles.BaseName[$i])"
        'Last Write Time' = $DocxFiles.LastWriteTime[$i]
            }
        }) | Out-Host
Write-Host ""

$input = Read-Host -Prompt "Select a file from the menu"
Clear-Host

$input = "$($DocxFiles[$input].FullName)"

If(Test-Path $input)
{

    # Open the document
    $doc = $word.Documents.Open($input)
    $word.Visible = $True
    # Get the first table in the document
    $table = $doc.Tables[1]

    # Cut the table
    $table.Range.Cut()

    # Move the cursor down the page
    $word.Selection.MoveDown([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits]::wdLine, 100, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdMovementType]::wdMove)

    # Paste the table
    $word.Selection.Paste()



    # Save and close the document
    $doc.Save()
    $doc.Close()
    Write-Host "The First Table in '$input' was moved" -ForegroundColor Green
}
Else
{
    Write-Host "The file '$input' does not exist" -ForegroundColor Red
} 
#release the com object
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word)
```

But nothing happened.

Comment: With VBA, you'd use code like ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Cells(1).Range.InsertBreak wdColumnBreak to insert a paragraph before the table. You can then use .Range(0,0) for inserting the new one.

Comment: Using PowerShell syntax, the above would be `$doc.Tables(1).Range.Cells(1).Range.InsertBreak(8)` (`8` --> `wdColumnBreak`, see [WdBreakType enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdbreaktype))